# Comparar Textos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito hacer un Insert a mi base de datos, mi tabla se llama "Tema" la cual guarda un idTema, textoTema y fecha. El punto es que cuando quiero insertar un tema, debo de checar si ya existe un tema similar (con otras palabras). Lo estoy haciendo algo asi...

```
select * from tema where textoTema like CONCAT('%', '".$variableConTexto."', '%');
```

Dicho query me regresa null... Existe alguna otra funcion para hacerlo..? que sea efectiva, ya que el anterior **query** al probarlo con una sola palabra o letra se jecuta perfectamente.

**PD: Estoy utilizando codeigniter**

Comment: podrías agregar un nuevo campo en la tabla que se llame titulo o algo similar, en cual dará la referencia al textoTema, luego preguntar si se repite el titulo con las respuestas de abajo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un índice de tipo `FULLTEXT` sobre el campo que quieres buscar y MySQL te retornará una respuesta aproximada del calce entre cadenas de texto aunque una no contenga exactamente a la otra:

```
create table palabras (
    palabra text,
    FULLTEXT idx (palabra)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into palabras (palabra) values ('casa'),
('casita'),
('mi casa'),
('tres casas'),
('perro'),
('alfombra'),
('mesa'),
('cama'),
('tejado'),
('cocina'),
('gato');
```

Existiendo el índice `FULLTEXT`, puedes usar la función `MATCH`.

```
SELECT palabra 
FROM palabras
WHERE MATCH(palabra) AGAINST('*una casa*')
```

Y te entregará las filas `casa` y `mi casa`.

[Fiddle de ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e49b/12).

Para que esto funcione vas a necesitar que existan al menos tres filas en tu tabla. De lo contrario no hay una prevalencia suficiente de palabras como para decidir si el texto se parece o no

Podrías también combinar los predicados resguardándote para ese caso de borde:

```
SELECT palabra 
FROM palabras
WHERE MATCH(palabra) AGAINST('*una casa*')
OR palabra LIKE '%una casa%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este query

```
SELECT * FROM tema WHERE textoTema LIKE '% $variableConTexto%'
```

Este deberia traer todas las coincidencias con el texto que se encuentre en $variableConTexto.

Comment: Hola.. Gracias por la respuesta, mira el punto aquí es que necesito comparar mas de una palabra por ejemplo la siguiente cadena de texto:

**Esto es una cadena de Texto**

Si por ejemplo mi variable lleva alguna palabra que se encuentre en la tabla, me deberia de arrojar que hay una coincidencia. Ya lo habia probado de esa manera, y me arroja **null**

Comment: Pero porque te da null? Estas recorriendo esos resultados? recuerda que eso te devolverá mas de un resultado. Por lo tanto haz probado recorrerlo?

Comment: Hola, mira ya lo intenté de dicha manera. el query me regresa un nulo.
En mi tabla de mysql tengo este registro

"Este es un tema Sugerido"

select * from tema where textoTema like '%tema sugerido%';

Yo esperaria que mínimo me regrese un resultado... pero no es así, me regresa Null

Comment: Haz probado la consulta directamente en phpMyAdmin? Si no te funciona asi tendras que probar con la funcion CONTAINS

Answer (score 0):

Buenas , has probado algo asi?

```
SELECT * FROM tema WHERE textoTema LIKE "%".$variableConTexto."%";
```

Comment: Hola.. Gracias por la respuesta, mira el punto aquí es que necesito comparar mas de una palabra por ejemplo la siguiente cadena de texto: Esto es una cadena de Texto Si por ejemplo mi variable lleva alguna palabra que se encuentre en la tabla, me deberia de arrojar que hay una coincidencia. Ya lo habia probado de esa manera, y me arroja null